# Why is the SelectedIndex in my DataGrid "-1"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

if i set property:

```
EnableRowVirtualization="True"
RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
SelectionMode="Extended"
SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

my datagrid, then:

```
int parse = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
```

return "-1", why?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have anything selected in the grid - remember it's a zero-based index, so the first 
row / item will return "0". According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx):

> SelectedIndex returns -1 if selection is empty

Your next line of code should be

```
if (parse >= 0)
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: Have you selected a row or cell?

Comment: of course, if i clear property RowDetailsVisibilityMode,SelectionMode and SelectionUnit, then works

Comment: @JohnSmith Don't mistake [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex) with row index from [DataGridRow.GetIndex Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.getindex).

Answer (score 1):

Most controls like this will return `SelectedIndex` as `-1` when nothing is selected.  (This is true of `ListBox` and `ComboBox` too, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

If the datagrid SelectionUnit="Cell" then you have to use

```
int parse = datagrid1.Items.IndexOf(datagrid1.CurrentItem)
```

If the datagrid SelectionUnit="FullRow" then you can use

```
int parse = datagrid1.SelectedIndex
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but still it gives *-1* if you click any row.